How to calculate the capacity of the transmit model?
I recently face the problem to work out the channel capacity of the following transmit model: The recieved signal
$$
{\boldsymbol{y}}=\boldsymbol{h}\left(\boldsymbol{Fx}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{N_r}\right)+{\boldsymbol{n}},
$$
where ${\boldsymbol{y}}\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times N_r}$, ${\boldsymbol{h}}\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times N_rN_t}$,
${\boldsymbol{x}}\in\mathbb{C}^{N_t\times 1}$,
${\boldsymbol{F}}\in\mathbb{C}^{N_t\times N_t}$,
${\boldsymbol{n}}\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times N_r}$ is the noise vector that follows the distribution of zero mean and $\sigma^2$ variance matrix.
${\boldsymbol{I}}_{N_r}$ is the $N_r\times N_r$ identity matrix. And $\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{n}$ are both independent CSCG vectors. $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.
I don't know how to derive the channel capacity. It's been troubling me for a long time and interrupted my research. If anyone knows how to handle it I'd appreciate it.

Does the receiver know what $F$ and $I_{N_r}$ are? I am assuming $h$ and $n$ approximately follow some known distribution as is usually the case?
